# How to import Sitecore XConnect (analytics) data from Sitecore 9.1.1 to Sitecore 10.01

Tags: xconnect, upgrade, migration

First some context. We are currently upgrading from Sitecore 9.1.1 and JSS 11 to Sitecore 10.01 and JSS 15. We do this by recreating the Azure PAAS infra using the ARM templates and custom Powershell scripts and afterwards deploying our own configuration and code. This works!

However we have had Sitecore XConnect (Analytics) up and running on our 9.1.1 platform and we do not want to lose that data.

We have tried making copies of the old databases running updates scripts on them and then restoring backups of those databases using the new Sitecore 10 names. This however is currently giving us all kinds of SQL errors and also not showing the actual data we imagined.

Anyone else here tried importing this data, and if so how did you do this?

Regards,
Jan-Pieter Hoiting